# Django tutorial urls.py problems

Tags: django

I can only seem to get the initial Django landing page, no matter what I try. I feel like I understand the way it should work but there is obviously something wrong. I have tried the polls tutorial and several others on youtube and I am constantly having the same problem where the urls.py doesn't seem to include the things I believe to be in there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## mysite/mysite/urls.py#

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include('polls.urls')),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

## mysite/polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

## mysite/polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

## Create your views here.

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world!")
```

Comment: Did you add `polls` app in installed_apps in your settings.py file?

Comment: @COSHW has the same thought, the `include` would crash the server. 
@OP what if you made it `path("test/", include('polls.urls')),` and visited `127.0.0.1:8000/test`, would that work?- also what version of Django?

Comment: @COSHW I have added polls to installed_apps in settings.py and also tried changing it to path("test/", include('polls.urls')), neither of which have made a difference, I still get 404 page not found when trying to visit /test. I am on version 4.1.7.